# What do the columns represent for the following Windbg command uf nt!KiSwapContext

Tags: windows, 64-bit, windbg

What do the first three columns stand for after entering the following command

**uf nt!KiSwapContext** ?

Here is the result displayed in the Windbg command prompt:

```
lkd> uf nt!KiSwapContext
nt!KiSwapContext:
fffff803`5c143fa0 4881ec38010000  sub     rsp,138h
fffff803`5c143fa7 488d842400010000 lea     rax,[rsp+100h]
fffff803`5c143faf 0f29742430      movaps  xmmword ptr [rsp+30h],xmm6
fffff803`5c143fb4 0f297c2440      movaps  xmmword ptr [rsp+40h],xmm7
fffff803`5c143fb9 440f29442450    movaps  xmmword ptr [rsp+50h],xmm8
fffff803`5c143fbf 440f294c2460    movaps  xmmword ptr [rsp+60h],xmm9
fffff803`5c143fc5 440f29542470    movaps  xmmword ptr [rsp+70h],xmm10
.....
```

Taking for example the following line as shown above what does the first three column addresses stand for ? Could someone also recommend a good place to start learning about the output rendered by Windbg if I wanted to try other Windbg commands ?

```
fffff803`5c143fa0 4881ec38010000  sub     rsp,138h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first column (`` fffff803`5c143fa0 ``) is the 64 bit instruction address, the backtick in the middle is only there to make the address easier to read by separating the upper and lower 32 bits of the address. More specifically it's the address of the first byte of the instruction.

The second column (`4881ec38010000`) is the bytes that make up the instruction, and the remainder of the line (`sub rsp,138h`) is the instruction decoded into the corresponding assembly (Intel syntax).

Comment: Thank you @Iridium. Can you tell me where I can read more about the interpretation of these columns ?

Comment: @JonnyBGood - the online help for WinDbg is quite comprehensive and would be a good place to start. Unfortunately more general recommendations for books and similar resources are considered off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Iridium@ are the addresses displayed in the first column a virtual address or physical address ?

Comment: @JonnyBGood - Those are virtual addresses.